# MySQL - Select value of JSON array based on the value of an element

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a TEXT variable in MySQL 5.7 that stores a JSON. Within this JSON there is a list with the following structure of N elements:

```
"brandedFares": [
{
"type": "name1",
"status": "allow"
},
{
"type": "name2",
"status": "not allowed"
},
...
```

The problem is that these elements may come in different order and some of those may be missing. I am building a summary table that can show if any of these elements come and their status.

| name1_exists | name1_status | name2_exists | name2_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | allow | TRUE | not allowed |

I tried to work it out with JSON_EXTRACT and substring_index but the fact that the list does not have an order kind of throws me out. Do you have any ideas or advices of how to do this within MySQL?

Comment: I don't think this is easy in MySQL. Don't use JSON if you need to perform queries like this, normalize your data.

Comment: This is what JSON_TABLE() is for in MySQL 8.0. If you're still using MySQL 5.7, I agree with Barmar, don't store this data in JSON format (or the format you show above, which is not legal JSON). Instead, store the data in normal rows and columns.

Comment: *I have a TEXT variable in MySQL 5.7* What do you mean? local variable? user-defined variable? something else? provide SQL code which assigns shown value to the variable and desired output for this value. *how to do this within MySQL?* Does complete list of possible attribute names exists?

Comment: Thanks, we will migrate to MySQL 8.0 in a few weeks, so I'll wait to that and use JSON_TABLE instead.